# Get already open exception even when using "MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, localdb

I'm using LocalDB in a WPF application. I get an `InvalidOperationException` with "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." even though I am using "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in my connection string.